# Hyperplane arrangements: Hyperplanes intersecting in a single point

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coxeter-groups

I'm currently reading a text about *hyperplane arrangements* in a euclidian vector space V. The text says:

> [...] without loss of generality, we may assume that some of the
> hyperplanes intersect in a single point otherwise we may pass to a
> cross region.

Would someone be so kind and elaborate why we may assume that some of the hyperplanes intersect in a single point?

The only possibility that came to my mind so far was, for example, three hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ intersecting in a single point, but i'm quite confident i'm still missing a few things here.

For context: this is about hyperplane arrangements that partition the euclidian vector space $V$ into chambers and i'm interested in the reflection group generated by the reflections in the walls of the hyperplane arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you arrangement is $A=\{H_i: i\in I\}$, where $H_i=\{f_i(x)+a_i=0\}$, where each $f_i$ is a nonzero linear functional on your vector space $V$. Let $F=\{f_i: i\in I\}$ denote the corresponding set of linear functionals. It is a nice linear algebra exercise to prove that the intersection $K$ of kernels of  functionals in $F$ is nonzero if and only if for every subset $J\subset I$,
$$
\bigcap_{i\in J} H_i
$$
is not a singleton (i.e. is empty or has positive dimension). Thus, either you have your point intersection, or $K\ne \{0\}$. In the latter case, $V\cong K\oplus V'$ and, accordingly, your arrangement consists of hyperplanes $H_i=K\oplus H_i'$, where $H_i'$ are affine hyperplanes in $V'$. The associated arrangement $A'= \{H'_i: i\in I\}$ now has the property that a subcollection of hyperplanes has point-intersection. This is what they mean by  "pass to a cross region" (which is quite sloppy).